Can I assign IP addresses to containers on a Docker network using dnsmasq?
We want to create a bunch of mock services that we can use to test our application.  In the real app, we will be assigning IP addresses using dnsmasq.  We will be disabling the DNS feature of dnsmasq.  This is our current configuration.
# Configuration file for dnsmasq.

# Listen on this specific port instead of the standard DNS port
# (53). Setting this to zero completely disables DNS function,
# leaving only DHCP and/or TFTP.
port=0

# Never forward plain names (with a dot or domain part)
domain-needed
# Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.
bogus-priv

# This lease time is short for demonstration purposes only.  In
# production it should be several hours.
dhcp-range=10.133.90.10,10.133.90.253,6m

# Log DHCP traffic.  We may want to disable this in production.
log-dhcp

# Set the DHCP server to authoritative mode. In this mode it will barge in
# and take over the lease for any client which broadcasts on the network,
# whether it has a record of the lease or not. This avoids long timeouts
# when a machine wakes up on a new network. DO NOT enable this if there's
# the slightest chance that you might end up accidentally configuring a DHCP
# server for your campus/company accidentally. The ISC server uses
# the same option, and this URL provides more information:
# http://www.isc.org/files/auth.html
dhcp-authoritative

We will be using the --dhcp-script option to run a script when leases are created.  This is why we don't want to use Docker's built-in DHCP facilities.  Is this possible?
So far, I've tried to create a small sample app using Docker Compose.  This is the *.yml file:
services:
  dhcp:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: dhcp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - internal
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
  client:
    build:
      context: client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
    name: dnsmasq_internal

The client is trival since I only care whether the IP address is assigned correctly.  This is the Dockerfile for the DHCP server.
FROM strm/dnsmasq

COPY dnsmasq.conf /etc

ENTRYPOINT [ "dnsmasq", "-k" ]

I want the addresses to be assigned on dnsmasq_internal, not the host network, so I don't think this question is relevant.  I am getting 172.* addresses so it seems like the built-in DHCP server is being used.
